# Better way to handle errors in tornado request handler

Tags: python, tornado

There are two similar handlers: AgeHandler1 and AgeHandler2. In the first one we simply raise a specific exception to return an error message, in the second - we manually return an error message. What You think about these two methods? Which method is preferable for a large project? Any other best practices?

```
import logging
import os.path
import traceback

from sys import exc_info
from tornado import web, options, ioloop

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class MyAppException(Exception):

    def __init__(self, message, code=400, *args, **kwargs):
        self.message = message
        self.code = code
        return super(MyAppException, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.message


class MyAppBaseHandler(web.RequestHandler):

    def handle_exception(self, e):
        exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = exc_info()
        logger.error(''.join([line for line in traceback.format_exception(
            exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb)]))
        if isinstance(exc_obj, MyAppException):
            self.set_status(exc_obj.code)
            self.write({'error': {
                'message': u'{exc_obj}'.format(exc_obj=exc_obj.message)}})
        else:
            self.set_status(500)
            fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
            self.write({'error': {
                'message': u'{exc_obj} in {fname} at {line}'.format(
                    exc_obj=exc_obj, fname=fname, line=exc_tb.tb_lineno)}})


class AgeHandler1(MyAppBaseHandler):

    def get(self):
        try:
            age = self.get_argument('age')
            age = int(age)
            if age < 1 or age > 200:
                raise MyAppException('Wrong age value.')
            self.write('Your age is {age}'.format(age=age))
        except Exception as e:
            self.handle_exception(e)


class AgeHandler2(MyAppBaseHandler):

    def get(self):
        age = self.get_argument('age')
        age = int(age)
        if age < 1 or age > 200:
            self.set_status(400)
            self.write('Wrong age value.')
            return
        self.write('Your age is {age}'.format(age=age))


class MyApplication(web.Application):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['handlers'] = [
            web.url(r'/age1', AgeHandler1, name='age1'),
            web.url(r'/age2', AgeHandler2, name='age2'),
        ]
        kwargs['debug'] = False
        super(MyApplication, self).__init__(**kwargs)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    options.parse_command_line()
    application = MyApplication()
    application.listen(5000)
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Responses:

```
"""
http://127.0.0.1:5000/age1
500: {"error": {"message": "HTTP 400: Bad Request (Missing argument age) in app.py at 44"}}
---
http://127.0.0.1:5000/age1?age=10
200: Your age is 10
---
http://127.0.0.1:5000/age1?age=201
400: {"error": {"message": "Wrong age value."}}
---
http://127.0.0.1:5000/age1?age=abc
500: {"error": {"message": "invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'abc' in app.py at 45"}}


http://127.0.0.1:5000/age2
400: <html><title>400: Bad Request</title><body>400: Bad Request</body></html>
---
http://127.0.0.1:5000/age2?age=10
200: Your age is 10
---
http://127.0.0.1:5000/age2?age=201
400: Wrong age value.
---
http://127.0.0.1:5000/age2?age=abc]
500: <html><title>500: Internal Server Error</title><body>500: Internal Server Error</body></html>
"""
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general the best approach is to override `RequestHandler.write_error`. This is similar to your first approach, but you don't need the try/except in the body of the handler because Tornado will handle this for you.

Explicit tests like those in your second example are also good, but it's impractical to catch all possible errors this way so you'll always need something to handle uncaught exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

Overwriting write_error works very well.  What I do in my projects is I try to catch any `500` status codes.  I then send them to myself over slack (my traffic is low enough that the frequency is very low).

Here's the code to extract a clean stack trace from `write_error`. Note in this example I also yank out any references to 'gen.py', 'concurrent.py' or 'web.py', which makes for much cleaner stack traces.

```
import tornado.web, traceback, logging

class MyRequestHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
   def write_error(self,status_code,**kwargs):
      if status_code == 500:
         excp = kwargs['exc_info'][1]
         tb   = kwargs['exc_info'][2]
         stack = traceback.extract_tb(tb)
         clean_stack = [i for i in stack if i[0][-6:] != 'gen.py' and i[0][-13:] != 'concurrent.py']
         error_msg = '{}\n  Exception: {}'.format(''.join(traceback.format_list(clean_stack)),excp)

         # do something with this error now... e.g., send it to yourself
         # on slack, or log it.
         logging.error(error_msg)  # do something with your error...

     # don't forget to show a user friendly error page!
     self.render("oops.html")
```

The output looks like this:

```
  File "app.py", line 55, in get
    assert 1==2,"A fake error to trigger a critical alert."

  Exception: A fake error to trigger a critical alert.
```

Answer (score 0):

For large projects, I would try to abstract from error numbers, specially because the definition of the HTTP status codes are not in your scope. As much I remember, there is at least one pair of status codes with problematic semantic. I don't remember which they where.

But for a larger project I would recommend, that you define your own error categories that you want to support and map those categories to HTTP codes centrally as you need. When you find out later, that you should use a different status code for some error category, you can do it centrally.

Logically I would try to factor out as much knowledge from the specific handling routine as possible. The exception model of course comes here handy, but similar could be reached with a function call for error handling like:

```
...
if age < 1 or age > 200:
   return self.errorResult('Wrong age value.', WRONG_VALUE)
...
```

or

```
...
if age < 1 or age > 200:
   return self.wrongValue('Wrong age value.')
...
```