# how to silence all exceptions in python tornado

Tags: python-3.x, tornado

I have a simple tornado app

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, world".s())

def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
    ], debug=False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

of course hitting `http://127.0.0.1:8888` will result in a long exception in my terminal like this

```
ERROR:tornado.application:Uncaught exception GET / (127.0.0.1)
 HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='127.0.0.1:8888', method='GET', uri='/', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='127.0.0.1', headers={'Host': '127.0.0.1:8888', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0', 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36', 'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch, br', 'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8'})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lib/python3.6/site- packages/tornado/web.py", line 1467, in _execute
    result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
  File "test.py", line 6, in get
    self.write("Hello, world".s())
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 's'
ERROR:tornado.access:500 GET / (127.0.0.1) 3.08ms
```

my question is how do I prevent uncaught exceptions' tracebacks and error messages from being printed to the stderr? I tried the `sys.excepthook` but it didint work with tornado for unknown reasons to me.

I am working with python 3.6 and tornado 4.4.2

Comment: if you only want to suppress error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5925918/python-suppressing-errors-from-going-to-commandline

Comment: seems good but I am looking more for some method in tornado's request handler that i can override to achieve this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26371051/better-way-to-handle-errors-in-tornado-request-handler

Comment: the log_exception method did the trick

Answer (score -1, accepted):

found it here  [log_exception method](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.log_exception)

By overriding the `log_exception` method you get to do whatever you want with that exception. In my case I only needed to `pass` just like this

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def log_exception(self, typ, value, tb):
        pass

    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, world".s())
```